# Can JQuery be debugged like javascript?

Tags: jquery, debugging

Hi,

Can we debug Jquery like what we can do for javascript using IE9 developer tools?
  I am facing severe problem when some jquery function is not being called  on some event.
  Is there any solution?Can you suggest any debugging tools if exists??

Comment: jQuery *is* javascript. just use the uncompressed variant to debug with...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery ***is*** javascript - it can be debugged in the exact same way, using the exact same tools. Personally I find the Firebug extension for Firefox the most usable.

It may be better for you to post the details of your problem in another question. I'm sure someone here will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can debug using `console.log()` or alert functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. jQuery is just a Javascript library, so you debug your Javascript just as usual.

The jQuery code is minified, so you might want to download and use the un-minified version if you want to debug the code in the jQuery library itself.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is Javascript, so it can be debugged using the IE9 developer tools.

The selectors can be a bit hard to debug, as it is not immediately visible in the debugger what elements match. Adding `alert()` calls to specific places might help.

Another trick I often use when debugging selectors is to insert a `css('background-color' , 'red')` to make the matched elements turn red.